# jquery validator with tooltip

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Is it possible to integrate the [jquery validator](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation) with a some sort of tooltip?

Here is what I am trying to do:
I have a contact form, onfocus of any fields, I want a real time tooltip to appear that directs the visitor into what to type, and once the tooltip is happy with the field value, it displays "accepted". Until then it reports an error e.g. "Name must be at least 5 characters", or "You must enter a valid email address."

Then on submit I want to show these tooltips for all the ones that were not accepted. I also want them to fadeIn and animate the same way as when on onfocus.
I also want these tooltips to fadeout, when I am infocus for one of the fields, and the field I am infocus cannot run through the animation of fadeIn, as it is already displayed.

Any ideas of how to do this easily?

Comment: you can have a div on some invisible area of the page, and when the use tries to type or alter a textbox you move that div near the textbox with your instructions injected to it. P.S: you only need one div for all fields

Comment: why would I need one div for all fields? Would there be elements inside the div that would be shown and hidden? i.e. if I am typing in an email address, I only want tooltip for email, not the other fields.

Comment: i mean, one div and you inject a different message for each field

Comment: You've detailed a long list of specific requirements without showing any real effort at coding this yourself.  I took one of my previous answers that uses the Tooltipster plugin and modified it a bit to meet most of your requirements below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is all what you need, it has animation too >>
[**FIDDLE Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/RUSPS/2/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
<input type="text" id="txt2" />
<div id="tt"></div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
 #tt{width:0px; height:0px; visibility':hidden; margin-left: -500px; background-color:red;}
```

---

**jQuery**

```
$('#txt1').focus(function(){
$('#tt').css({'width':'200px', 'height':'50px', 'visibility':'visible', 'background-color':'red'}).html('you clicked text field ONE').animate({'marginLeft':'10px'},1000)
});
$('#txt2').focus(function(){
    $('#tt').css({'width':'300px', 'height':'50px', 'visibility':'visible', 'background-color':'yellow'}).html('you clicked text field TWO').animate({'marginLeft':'150px'},1000)
});
```

Comment: The OP is looking for integration with the jQuery Validate plugin.

Answer (score 1):

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/bvu5f/**

This answer uses a jQuery plugin called [Tooltipster](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/) along with the jQuery Validate plugin.

First, initialize the Tooltipster plugin ([with any options](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/#options)) on **all** specific `form` elements that will display errors:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    // initialize tooltipster on form input elements
    $('#myform input[type="text"]').tooltipster({ 
        trigger: 'custom', // default is 'hover' which is no good here
        onlyOne: false,    // allow multiple tips to be open at a time
        position: 'right'  // display the tips to the right of the element
    });

});
```

Second, use [Tooltipster's advanced options](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/#advanced) along with the [`success:` and `errorPlacement:` callback functions built into the Validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) to automatically show and hide the tooltips as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    // initialize validate plugin on the form
    $('#myform').validate({
        // any other options & rules,
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            $(element).tooltipster('update', $(error).text());
            $(element).tooltipster('show');
        },
        success: function (label, element) {
            // $(element).tooltipster('hide'); // normal validate behavior
            $(element).tooltipster('update', 'accepted'); // as per OP
        }
    });

});
```

Code takes advantage of the new Tooltipster API features released in version 2.1 on 2/12/13

Comment: Nice plugin, its size is large though, js+css ~ 41kB, do they enable the user to pick blocks of code he/she needs only?

Comment: @JEES, I am not sure about that... I've only recently started replacing qTip2 with [Tooltipster](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/) because it's easier to use and way easier to configure for a consistent cross-browser look & feel; plus Tooltipster has some nice built-in animation options similar to what the OP requested.  41 kb doesn't bother me too much when most people no longer use dial-up.

Comment: No doubt it's a time saving option if you want an all-purpose playcard, but most plugins add size and more http-requests, most of the stylish includes css and js and that's 2 requests for each plugin! personally I prefer writing my own codes.

Comment: @JEES, it all comes down to how much time you want to spend re-inventing something and thoroughly testing it all browser flavors.  Another couple requests and 41 kb is really almost nothing when compared to the dozens of scripts and requests made by a popular site like Facebook or eBay.

Comment: All is well that ends well :)