# jQuery Validation & Tooltipter Show One Validation Message At A Time

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, tooltipster

I''m using jQuery validation and tooltipster to show error messages which is working fine. However i want to show one error message at a time working from the top of the form. At the moment i get every invalid field showing.

So say if item 4 has just been filled out but item 3 has not been filled in correctly the validation messages shows on 3 till that has been filled in correctly.

Here's my code so far using [jquery validator with tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408449/jquery-validator-with-tooltip)

```
$('#myform input[type="text"]').tooltipster({
                trigger: 'custom',
                onlyOne: false,
                position: 'top'
            });


            $('#myform').validate({
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

                    $(element).tooltipster('update', $(error).text());
                    $(element).tooltipster('show');
                },
                success: function (label, element) {
                    $(element).tooltipster('hide');
                },
                rules: {
                    EmailId: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    Password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5

                    },
                    ComparePassword: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5,
                        equalTo: "#Password"

                    },
                    FirstName: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    LastName: {
                        required: true


                }

                },

            });
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *"However i want to show one error message at a time"*

Perhaps you missed this option?

```
$('#myform input[type="text"]').tooltipster({
    trigger: 'custom',
    onlyOne: false, // <--  THIS HERE
    position: 'top'
});
```

[From the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16408788/594235):

```
onlyOne: false,    // allow multiple tips to be open at a time
```

Comment: Great thanks, i thought that option was to just show the validation message once, i misread.